# Tag-related hint pages OR tag-related check-list that appears before question is posted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags

There is **a lot** of low-quality questions, that could be answered e.g. using just a damn debugger in less then 5 minutes. These questions just produce 'noise' as they do not bring any *value* to the community.

I was thinking in having tag-related **pages** with some generic hints that may help in solving trivial problems. Sure, these pages would not be a big knowledge base, but maybe just little hints and links to the other sites. These pages would be written by users with higher reputation.

For example, if someone tags a question with `java`, there would be links to hint pages: *java collections*, *debugging java* etc. So its like tag description that we already have plus additional content.

OR...

... as  I am afraid that even if this exist, users will still be lazy to use that - instead of pages we would have tag-related checklist questions. For example, if user tags question with `java`, a checklist would appear above "Post Your Question" with checkbox questions like: *did you try to debug it?*, *did you check API docs?*, *do you have stack trace*? etc. (each question may have little popup explaining it self). As reputation grows, number of these questions is reduced.

Just thinking out loud...

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this functionality already provided by tag wikis?

For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info

There is even a [java](/questions/tagged/java)-specific FAQ in that wiki.